# Upload an image and getting url

Tags: java, android, image, image-uploading

I've been working on my capstone project which I need to find a way to upload an Image to a webserver in my app (I'm also learning new concepts webservers,php etc..) and get an url of the image back which can be used globally.I mean it should be public(I'm going to use it for reverse google search). I was trying to achieve this by using ftp on free webervers but I failed.

I believe I understood easy android development concepts bu I'm still a rookie and of course there cant be "copy paste this and you're good to go" method but I could really use a suggestion or a tip If you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out google [firebase cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

It'll do exactly what you're after, plus the [tutorials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) are great

Comment: thnx for reply,however download url's from firebase are returning as error for reverse image search.But I managed to upload files easily so it's something.